How do I create a variable with mutate() that has values equal to the name of a given variable?
I would like to create a variable with mutate() that will have values equal to the name of a given variable. I need this to change dynamically.
This is the function that I wrote:
fn <- function(data, var_1) {
  
  var_1 <- enquo(var_1)
  
  prop <- data %>%
    mutate(Indicator = label(!!var_1))
  
}

Here the Indicator variable has the label of var_1 as values. I would like it to have as values the name of var_1.

We can use rlang::as_label():
library(dplyr)

foo <- function(data, var_1) {
  
  var_1 <- enquo(var_1)
  
  data |> 
    mutate(Indicator = rlang::as_label(var_1))
}

foo(mtcars, hp) |> 
  head()

#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb Indicator
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4        hp
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4        hp
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1        hp
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1        hp
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2        hp
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1        hp

Created on 2024-05-02 with reprex v2.1.0
